# how to store clicked images from database in php?

Tags: php

I stored some images in array and display as the image is shuffled in each refresh.Now i want to store the image which I selected from screen using php. please help me.Here is the code

```
<?php
$images = array(
'<a href='#'><img src="images/images (4).jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></a>',
'<a href='#'><img src="images/images (6).jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></a>',
'<a href='#'><img src="images/images (5).jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></a>', 
'<a href='#'><img src="images/drt.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></a>',
'<a href='#'><img src="images/rf.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></a>', 
'<a href='#'><img src="images/yu.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></a>',
'<a href='#'><img src="images/ed.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></a>');
shuffle($images); // Randomize images array;
?>
<?php echo $images[0];?>
<?php echo $images[1];?>
<?php echo $images[2];?>
```

Comment: You're going to need to write some HTML and/or Javascript code to handle that functionality. Wrap your images in `<a>` tags that point to a PHP file specifying the name of the image.  Then store it from that file.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

```
$images = array("img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg");
shuffle($images); // for randomaize
    //save  $images[0], $images[1],  into  database here

    // and echo here..
echo "<img src=\"images/$images[0]\" alt=\"\" width=\"234\" height=\"212\" />\n";
echo "<img src=\"images/$images[0].jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"234\" height=\"212\" />\n";
```

Comment: Thanku and actally i want to store one or two images in database only which I clicked or select from screen from all displayed images.

Comment: Then have to use checkbox for select image and store these by form post or ajax.. Do you know ajax?

Comment: whether i created any html forms??

Comment: look below the code given by olim..it canot display image randomly.bt the design is ok.whether i can included above php code

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each `img` in a label with checkbox and send selection like an simple html form. But before that you must somehow identify images by some attribute i.e image file name. Example:

```css
.image-select-form input[type=checkbox] {
  position:absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}



.image-select-form label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relatice;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.image-select-form label img{
  display: block;
}

.image-select-form input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="select.php" method="post" class="image-select-form">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected_images" value="rf.jpg" checked id="img1">
      <label for="img1"><img src="images/rf.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selected_images" value="drt.jpg" id="img2">
      <label for="img2"><img src="images/drt.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selected_images" value="yu.jpg" id="img3">
      <label for="img3"><img src="images/yu.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="selected_images" value="ed.jpg" id="img4">
      <label for="img4"><img src="images/ed.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" /></label>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit selected images">
</form>
```

In php which handle form i.e. `select.php` just access `$_POST['selected_images']` which stores selected images file names